# Python : Find Common Text in Two Files

Tags: python, sed, gawk

Let me give the example text files :

e.g.
in **file1.txt** The data is:-

```
qwer
asdf
zxcv
1234
```

in **file2.txt** The data is:-

```
0987
5678
uiop
qwer
zxcv
```

**Desired result:**

```
qwer
zxcv
```

How do I get this result? I want to use `python` or `gawk` or `sed`.

Comment: hi, we run this "comm -12 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file1.txt)" ok in linux os, but windows 7 os fail,ths!
in windows 7 os:
sort file1.txt >out1.txt
sort file2.txt >out2.txt
comm -12 out1.txt out2.txt
result pass

Answer (score 6):

I'd use Python sets for this:

```
file1 = set(line.strip() for line in open('file1.txt'))
file2 = set(line.strip() for line in open('file2.txt'))

for line in file1 & file2:
    if line:
        print line
```

Comment: Can this match string of any lengths?

Answer (score 3):

Use [comm](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=comm):

```
comm -12 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt)
```

With gawk:

```
gawk 'NR==FNR {file1[$0]++; next} $0 in file1' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Comment: comm -12 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt), we use this command line show "The system can not find the file specified" and windows 7 os 64 bit